How do draw a pie chart in react native
How can I draw a donut chart?
I tried using react-native-gifted-charts
i want some animation for fill the chart.Is there any library that can resolve this? someone is help me to do this i want exactly like this with animation

what type of animation in donut chart you want ?

@ABDULLAH i want like how the circular progress bar's are filling with animation my pie chart  need to fill with animation


You can use other libraries as well for animate the circular progrees
of your donut chart  you can custom define your animation and modify
it as well.
use below libraries

import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';
import Svg, { G, Circle } from 'react-native-svg';


and you can adjust the donut according to your need

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);

const DonutChart = ({ percentage }) => {
  const radius = width / 6;
  const strokeWidth = 40;
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
  const animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const animatedProps = {
    strokeDashoffset: animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [circumference, circumference - (circumference * percentage) / 100],
    }),
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1500,
      easing: Easing.out(Easing.quad),
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [percentage]);


and adjust your svg with viewBox height and width

return (
    <View >
      <Svg width={radius * 2 + strokeWidth} height={radius * 2 + strokeWidth} viewBox={`0 0 ${radius * 2 + strokeWidth} ${radius * 2 + strokeWidth}`}>
        <G rotation="-90" origin={`${radius + strokeWidth / 2}, ${radius + strokeWidth / 2}`}>
          <Circle
            cx={radius + strokeWidth / 2}
            cy={radius + strokeWidth / 2}
            r={radius}
            stroke="#e6e6e6"
            strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            fill="none"
          />
          <AnimatedCircle
            cx={radius + strokeWidth / 2}
            cy={radius + strokeWidth / 2}
            r={radius}
            stroke="green"
            strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            fill="none"
            strokeDasharray={circumference}
            {...animatedProps}
          />
        </G>
      </Svg>
    </View>
  );


after that set your percentage of progress

<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <DonutChart percentage={90} />
    </View>


also i have share the full code of expo snack link below and modify it
as per your need

Expo Pie chart Link

its working but i want multiple colors because i receive a percentage from api like [20,30,10,50] like this  and it is possible to add the text 20% 30% in above the the colors?

i have update the code in expo please do visit the link above mention in the answer.

yes but green is not filled  fully there is a  space between red and green

set the percentage to 100

@ ABDULLAH let we take like this overall percentage is 100 green should filled 40% of the circle blue should 30% of the circle red should filled 10%  the circle the whole circle is filled with colour with out empty space could you please help me for this?

Check the expo link now

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
